# How to format sql which has "%" in condition in Python3.7

Tags: sql, format

I am trying to use f string to format the SQL below in Python 3.7:

```
"SELECT job_id, job_type, job_desc FROM status WHERE status_desc like 'Status for JOB1%' and job_type = 1"
```

I have tried it in this way

```
condition1 = "\'Status for JOB1%\'"
query = f"""SELECT job_id, job_type, job_desc
            FROM status
            WHERE status_desc like {condition1 } and job_type = 1"""
```

It returns "Invalid Python format string for query".

Comment: use a prepared statement and please show where you run your query

Comment: Can you tag the DBMS please ..?